# Tire blow out 1997 dodge ram

Tags: tires, dodge, ram

A buddy of mine changed the brake pads on the passenger side of my truck, ran out of time to do drivers side.  I drove a couple days not many miles.  I was on expressway and my tire started to go flat, pulled over and this is what I saw, the whole sidewall blew out.  Also I just had all 4 tires put on about 2 weeks ago.  My question is, if doing only one side of brakes could of caused this?

Comment: So, what did you see? could be a faulty tire - who can tell?

Comment: _this is what I saw_  Did you mean to supply a photo?

Comment: No, he was just explaining what he saw, not showing you.

Answer (score 1):

To my mind, there is no way changing out the brakes on the single side would have any effect on the tire. To me it sounds as though you got a bad tire. I'm assuming the tires you installed are new since you did all four. As long as this is true, take them back and get a new tire put on in place of it, because obviously (to me anyway) you got a defective tire.